# Last minute hotel deals

Tags: hotels

I am just curious if last minute hotel deals is actually a thing. I am not a big traveler and have no clue.

But in theory if a hotel has a bunch of empty rooms for the current day, it would make sense to rent them at a reduced rate as opposed to letting them be empty.

Is this actually a thing that could be leveraged?

I am going on a road trip, and the last leg of the trip could take many variations on a moments notice and was wondering if this is something I could take advantage of.

Comment: Sure, many businesses and "startups" completely cover this business space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, in fact, a thing.

One source is the app [Hotel Tonight](https://www.hoteltonight.com/), which works with hotels to post last-minute room availability. Your success will vary a lot depending on the city, season, and events going on, but it's worth looking to see what you can find.

Answer (score 4):

So as mentioned in the other answer, you have Hotel Tonight and then there is also [Very Last Room](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/verylastroom-hotel-derniere/id533146853?mt=8).

Then another way to obtain last minute rates is to directly reach out to the hotel and ask them for a last minute discount. Some will deny and some will be happy to offer this to you...